# MAAS / Juju bootstrap - node installation via PXE loops at partitioner step

Tags: server, partitioning, juju, maas

I am trying to setup a MAAS / Juju / Openstack environment.

Currently I've installed Juju on the MAAS server and am trying to run the `juju bootstrap` command.

In the terminal I can see (using -v) it's trying to connect to 1 of my nodes (which despite having IPMI configured correct, I have to power-on myself).

Then it will start the ubuntu installation via PXE on the chosen node, going through all the installation steps automatically and will eventually reach the **"starting up the partitioner"** step doing nothing but repeating that step over and over again.

Eventually after about 10 minutes my juju bootstrap command tells me it takes too long and destroys the envirment causing the node to power-off without installing anything.

This is the PuTTY ssh from the MAAS server (which also contains the Juju installation):

```
root@masternode:/home/user# juju bootstrap
Launching instance
WARNING picked arbitrary tools &{"1.18.4-trusty-amd64" "https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.18244874ffec4af083cdeb58040420320f63ac6a3f7526c81d963fa4e53d6" %!q(int64=7389403)}
 - /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-21ff183c-fc94-11e3-ba73-0013723f9f8b/
Waiting for address

=== This is where the problem described above starts ===

Attempting to connect to 7mb4j.local:22
ERROR bootstrap failed: waited for 10m0s without being able to connect: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 7mb4j.local
Stopping instance...
Bootstrap failed, destroying environment
ERROR waited for 10m0s without being able to connect: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 7mb4j.local: Name or service
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with 7 dell PowerEdge SC1425 servers (1 maas server + 6 nodes).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix this, turned out it wasn't properly detecting my raid configuration.

During the install I pressed CTRL + ALT + F2 and opened up another console, then I ran the command `dmraid -ay` and everything continued as it should